# error al hacer git push a mi proyecto hecho en PHP

Tags: php, git, github

Tengo este problema, sucede que quiero subir mi proyecto a un repositorio de git hub.

Entonces ejecuto este comando:

```
git push -u origin main
```

Me sale una ventana donde escribo el token (el token ya lo generé y lo escribo tal y como me lo genera), ahora bien, me sale este error:

```
fatal: An error occurred while sending the request.
```

fatal: Anulada la solicitud: No se puede crear un canal seguro SSL/TLS.

```
Username for 'https://github.com': NombredeUsuario
Password for 'https://NombredeUsuario@github.com':
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/NombredeUsuario/nombre_del_repo.git/'
```

Comment: Claramente te indica que GitHub eliminó el soporte de token desde agosto 2021. Quizá esta pregunta pueda ayudarte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68775869/message-support-for-password-authentication-was-removed-please-use-a-personal

Comment: Authentication con token sirve, aunque creo que el OP no lo está haciendo de forma correcta.  Lo que eliminaron fue la autenticado con usuario/password, que es lo que dice el mensaje

Comment: Muchas gracias @EvilFearzZ, me ayudó bastante tu respuesta